# Leetcode 176. Second highest salary

Tags: mysql

In a given question,

Write a SQL query to get the second highest salary from the Employee table.

```
+----+--------+
| Id | Salary |
+----+--------+
| 1  | 100    |
| 2  | 200    |
| 3  | 300    |
+----+--------+
```

For example, given the above Employee table, the query should return 200 as the second highest salary. If there is no second highest salary, then the query should return null.

```
+---------------------+
| SecondHighestSalary |
+---------------------+
| 200                 |
+---------------------+
```

I submited the query below
(window function to rank the salary then identify ifnull or not):

```
WITH salary_ranked 
AS (
    SELECT 
        salary,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC) AS rank_num
    FROM
        Employee
    )
SELECT
    IFNULL(
        (SELECT salary_ranked.salary
        FROM salary_ranked
        WHERE rank_num =2), 'null') AS SecondHighestSalary;
```

But it showed the wrong answer as below.
[image]

> **THE LATEST UPDATE**

Revised the code below:

```
WITH salary_ranked 
AS (
    SELECT 
        salary,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC) AS rank_num
    FROM
        Employee
    WHERE
        salary > 0
    )
SELECT
    IFNULL(
        (SELECT salary_ranked.salary
        FROM salary_ranked
        WHERE rank_num =2), null) AS SecondHighestSalary;
```

It passed 7 test cases of 8. But it still leave the last situation to be solved.
[image]

Comment: Why not simply use `LIMIT` with offset? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

Comment: Your rank query looks correct.  What is the actual output?

Comment: I doubt it wants the string "null"; try scrapping the IFNULL and just do `select (select salary from salary_ranked where rank_num=2)`.  possibly it should be rank instead of dense_rank; the problem isn't clear about that

Comment: First of all, thank you for the all comments. I have tried the limit 1 offset 1 condition, but it didn't answer the null situation.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The output seems correct, I have uploaded the system feedback below.

Comment: Change `IFNULL(... ,'null')`   to `IFNULL(... , null)`.   The value `'null'` is a string, and makes the return value also a CHAR() (or a VARCHAR() ).   (see, for more info on NULL values: [Working with NULL Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/working-with-null.html))

Comment: @Luuk After revising the code you mentioned, it passed the 7 test cases of 8. But it still failed in the last test case. I have uploaded the screenshot on my question above.

Comment: Luckily some room for learning SQL yourself is left as an exercise.  I have no clue what testcase 8 is about, because I am not following these Leetcode samples. Also on stackoverflow it is required to show complete code, and description about desired results. So, Why do you think testcase 8 failed, and what is testcase 8 ?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, salary FROM employees ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 1, 1
```

The first number after "LIMIT" is the offset when using the comma. The offset is zero-indexed. So, this query selects one row, starting at the second highest.

See the section on ["offset"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) in the MySQL docs on SELECT

Comment: This fails if there are two or more salaries tied for the highest.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the question didn't explain what to do in case if 2 top values are the same, hence - it does not matter.

Comment: if there is only one employee, null should be returned; returning no row is definitely wrong.  if there are ties for highest salary, either the next highest salary or null should be returned, depending how you read the problem statement; returning the highest salary is definitely wrong.

Comment: @ysth "returning the highest salary is definitely wrong" --- it's not.

Comment: @zerkms ok, I will acknowledge that it is possible someone writing the problem would have meant that.  but if the salaries are 300, 300, 100, I would give a 1% chance that 300 is wanted, vs maybe 10% that null is wanted (and the remaining 89% that 100 is wanted)

Comment: @ysth conflict case should be explicitly defined in the task, if it's not explicitly defined - any answer suits. Ranging it by percents does not make much sense to me - it's either defined and known, or not defined and any is good.